# How to Transpose a resultset from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.
I have a table that looks something like this:

```
|======================================================|
| RespondentId | QuestionId | AnswerValue | ColumnName | 
|======================================================|
|     P123     |      1     |     Y       | CanBathe   |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|     P123     |      2     |     3       | TimesADay  |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|     P123     |      3     |     1.00    | SoapPrice  |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|     P465     |      1     |     Y       | CanBathe   |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|     P465     |      2     |     1       | TimesADay  |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|     P465     |      3     |     0.99    | SoapPrice  |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|     P901     |      1     |     N       | CanBathe   |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|     P901     |      2     |     0       | TimesADay  |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|     P901     |      3     |     0.00    | SoapPrice  |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

I would like to flip the rows to be columns so that this table looks like this:

```
|=================================================|
| RespondentId | CanBathe | TimesADay | SoapPrice | 
|=================================================|
|     P123     |     Y    |      3    |   1.00    | 
|-------------------------------------------------|
|     P465     |     Y    |      1    |   0.99    | 
|-------------------------------------------------|
|     P901     |     N    |      0    |   0.00    | 
|-------------------------------------------------|
```

*(the example data here is arbitrarily made up, so its silly)*

The source table is a temp table with approximately 70,000 rows.
What SQL would I need to write to do this?

**Update**

- I don't even know if PIVOT is the right way to go.
- I don't know what column to PIVOT on.
- The documentation mentions `<aggregation function>` and `<column being aggregated>` and I don't want to aggregate anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into `PIVOT`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: from what I have seen of the `PIVOT` command, you have to use an aggregate function. I don't want an aggregate function, I just want the values to be flipped around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It, is required to use an aggregate function if you use `PIVOT`. However, since your `(RespondentId, QuestionId)` combination is unique, your "groups" will have only one row, so you can use `MIN()` as an aggregate function:

```
SELECT RespondentId, CanBathe, TimesADay, SoapPrice
FROM (SELECT RespondentId, ColumnName, AnswerValue FROM MyTable) AS src
PIVOT (MIN(AnswerValue) FOR ColumnName IN(CanBathe, TimesADay, SoapPrice)) AS pvt
```

If a group only contain one row, then `MIN(value) = value`, or in other words: the aggregate function becomes the identity function.

Answer (score 1):

See if [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) gets you started. Used to have to use CASE statements to make that happen but it looks like some inkling of PIVOT is in SQL Server now.

Answer (score 0):

PIVOT is a start, but the thing with sql queries is that you really need to know what columns to expect in the result set *before* writing the query.  If you don't know this, the last time I checked you have to either resort to dynamic sql or allow the client app that retrieves the data to do the pivot instead.

Comment: There are a fixed number of columns (65 - one for each survey question), its just that their names are stored as data.

Comment: In that case, pivot should do what you need, but you will have to put in an entry in your select list for each column