# How to turn bring columns in rows using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following result which i have got after using this query :

```
select SCHOOL_YEAR,COUNT(MUSIC) as ct,MUSIC from [table1]
group by SCHOOL_YEAR,MUSIC;

SCHOOL_YEAR   ct      MUSIC

2011          100     Piano
2011          50      Violin
2012          70      Piano
2012          150     Violin
```

I want it in the following format :

```
SCHOOL_YEAR   Piano     Violin

2011           100        50
2012           70         150
```

How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Please check the transpose in sql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699997/sql-server-transpose-rows-into-columns[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699997/sql-server-transpose-rows-into-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pivot query on the original table, but aggregate only on the school year:

```
SELECT
    SCHOOL_YEAR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MUSIC = 'Piano'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Piano,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MUSIC = 'Violin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Violin
FROM table1
GROUP BY
    SCHOOL_YEAR
```

Comment: That would count the rows for each "music", instead of "THEN 1" it should be `music`.

Comment: @SloanThrasher The `MUSIC` column is text, not a number, read the question.  The only issue here would be counting NULL values.  My summation would ignore NULL, as would the `COUNT()` function.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I think instead of `1` and `0` should use `ct`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: You are right, my mistake. It should be ct and 0.

Comment: @Wanderer The original table has no such column called `ct`.  _Read the question_.